# Getting "CF-InvalidAuthToken(1000): Invalid Auth Token" while launching the tasks in Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.11.1

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui, spring-data-flow

Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.11.1 showing below error.
org.cloudfoundry.client.v2.ClientV2Exception: CF-InvalidAuthToken(1000): Invalid Auth Token
16:56:26.513: [APP/PROC/WEB.0]  at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMappers.lambda$null$0(ErrorPayloadMappers.java:49)

We tried disabling the authorization by adding the property "spring:cloud:dataflow:security:authorization:enabled:
false" and "spring.cloud.dataflow.security.cf-use-uaa".

Note: Getting this error only after 24 hrs of deployment/restart.